# How can I select pictures from iPhoto into my Cocoa application using Applescript / Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, iphoto

I have a image editing Cocoa Mac application that takes a few image files (jpeg, png, tiff, gif etc.) as input. I would like to provide the user with a button in my application to get these input image files from iPhoto.

I would like a dialog/popup with iPhoto pictures to open when the user clicks this button. The user can then select some pictures in this dialog/popup. On dialog close after selection I would like to get the paths of the pictures selected.

Please suggest how i can achieve this.

**Edited by Abizern following the comment on my answer**

I'd rather not use a third party framework - is there a way to do this with Applescript or Automator workflows from within my application?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Karelia iMedia Browser](http://code.google.com/p/imedia/) which you can add as a framework to your project.

Not just iPhoto pictures, but also pictures on your hard disk, and pictures from Flickr.

Comment: I would not like to use a third party framework, isn't this somehow easily possible using apple script / automator workflows

Comment: Why put objective-c and Cocoa tags on the question, then?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that will pop up iPhoto itself and allow the user to select some photos and then continue.   Hopefully your program can provide a more elegant modeless way for the user to signal that they're done.

```
tell application "iPhoto"
    activate

    display alert "After you click OK, you will have 10 seconds to select some photos or albums"
    delay 10

    set paths to {}
    repeat with s in (get selection)
        set i to properties of s
        if class of i is album then
            repeat with p in photos of album (name of i)
                copy image path of p to end of paths
            end repeat
        else if class of i is photo then
            copy image path of i to end of paths
        end if
    end repeat

    log paths
end tell
```